# com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: Unknown JAXBContext implementation: class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

Tags: web-services

We have an EJB3.1 stateless session bean annotated with @WebserviceProvider. Somehow while throwing the soap fault exception we get the below exception. This service is deployed on weblogic 12c and it uses Jdk 1.7. Has someone else faced this issue ? Could you help. Thanks in advance.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: Unknown JAXBContext implementation:
class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getJAXBFactory(BindingCon
textFactory.java:204)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFact
ory.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuil
der.java:423)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaul
tBuilder.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaul
tBuilder.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.WsaServerTube.processException(WsaServerTub
e.java:214)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:887)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:841)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:804)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:706)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:43
0)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdap
ter.java:640)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:265
)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAd
apter.java:163)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:1
71)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServl
etAdapter.java:708)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
dSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
146)
        at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSec
urityHelper.java:103)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:
311)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:3
36)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
        at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServl
et.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run
(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run
(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecuri
tyHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.jav
a:338)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.jav
a:221)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
n.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
dSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:
57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAp
pServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppS
ervletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletC
ontext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.j
ava:1513)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExec
utor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem? I have the same problem on Websphere 8.5.5.7

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and managed to fix it by fixing small bug in wsdl file. Im my case wsdl had definition of two operations with request and response types. Second operation was using types defined for first operation just like example below:

```
<wsdl:message name="SecondOperationRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:FirstOperationrequestType"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

after fixing it to:

```
<wsdl:message name="FirstOperationRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:FirstOperationrequestType"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

before there was only a name that distinguished those operations.